# Master Database Occasionally Gets Corrupted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been experiencing an issue with our Windows Update server where the *master* database appears to occasionally get corrupted at random times. We're running a Windows Internal Database (which seems to be equivalent to SQL Server 2012).

It's happened at least three times since migrating to a Windows 2012 R2 Server from a Windows 2008 Server (both are VMs). Every time it's happened it results in me restoring the *master* database by swapping out the data and log files with the master template files, then re-attaching the SUSDB.

What typically happens is that we'll see that the Windows Internal Database service is not running, which typically sparks the following troubleshooting steps:

- Try to restart the service, which doesn't work.
- Try to open the SQL Server instance via SSMS, which doesn't work (it sits and spins for a long time).
- Look in the SQL Server logs, where I'll see some or all of the following messages:

  - > Error: 50000, Severity: 16, State: 1.
  - > Detected an unauthorized object in the schema
  - > Database verification script failed for database 'master'.
  - > Error: 3605, Severity: 16, State: 1.
  - > Schema verification failed for database 'master'.
- I've searched for these error codes and troubleshot, but the only thing that seems to work is completely replacing the *master* database. I hesitate to say I've tried everything, but I'm pretty sure I've tried everything.

Some of the things that I've tried/pondered:

- I'm the only DBA on the server, so files are not being moved around.
- I've made sure that the "compress contents to save disk space" has not be checked in the advanced attributes in the data folder.
- Because of the size of the SUSDB, we can't switch to using SQL Server Express instead of WID.

**Questions**

So my questions are:

- Does anyone have any insight into how I can prevent this from happening again?
- Or possibly someone has a better solution for when it does occur?

As I said, it appears to happen at random and my fix is not exactly perfect. Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd definitely look to see what filter drivers are loaded and make sure that you're not doing anything weird with the vm on things like backups or 3rd party agents.